# Variable name of mxArray pointer

Tags: matlab, mex

Is it possible to get the variable name of a mxArray pointer?

```
const char * strFileMatFile = "path/to/mat/file.mat";
pMatFile = matOpen(strFile, "r");

const char * strVarName = "a" // name of a variable inside the mat file
                              // which I want to find with the mxArray pointer
// Get a pointer to the variable with name strVarName in the mat file
mxArray *pVariable = matGetVariable(pMatFile, strVarName);


const char * strVarNameFromPtr = mxArrayToString(pVariable);
```

`mxArrayToString(pVariable)` returns null. Is there a function that can return the variable name of a mxArray pointer?

Something like:

```
const char * strVarNameFromPtr = mxGetName(pVariable);
```

Comment: What to you *really* need? This looks like the classic [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). What do you need the variable name for? Isn't the variable name `"a"`?

Comment: I would like to parse a variable inside a mat file just by its pointer because I have nested structs. And I want to avoid storing all the variabl enames. However, I face another issue reading the content of nested structs.

Comment: The thing is, you are in C now. The variable name is  `pVariable`, not `"a"`, anymore. You can not have the flexibility that you have with MATLAB in C, as they are fundamentally different languages. You need to be explicit in C. I suggest you have a look at C structs or ven C++ classes to handle your complicated structures. Or even better, find a non-complicate way of storing them.

Comment: You are right. I was thinking on a high level and that I can simply get the name from the pointer.

Comment: Another question: Do you know how to get the content of a nested struct? I tried with `mxArray * pField = mxGetField(pStruct, eIdx, strFieldName)` but it returns null when `eIdx` is not zero. I guess the problem is that this function is only useful for struct arrays. Or am I using the function incorrectly for nested structs?

Comment: I guess if you have a nested struct, you should do nested `mexGetField`, no? Try that, it should work I think

Comment: I cannot find the funciton `mexGetField` and I also tried google to find a way reading nested structs in C. The only thing I found is this https://de.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/102791-how-can-i-build-nested-mxstructs-in-c-for-use-with-matlab-mex-files-or-the-matlab-compiler. However, using `pField = mxGetField(i_pStruct, 0, strFieldName);` seems to work if the field does not contain a string.

Comment: What do you mean you can not find it XD You proposed it in your comment.

Comment: `mexGetField` vs `mxGetField`. I thought you meant another function.

Comment: I made a typo.....

Comment: Thanks for your help! If I encounter another problem I will make a new question.

Comment: Consider deleting this one, as its rather an initial misunderstanding than a real problem.